# PDO fulltext search troubleshooting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this has been posted a lot but since I'm very new to PDO I couldn't find an answer for the problem I'm having with the PDO fulltext search. I have the following code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST(:sq)";
$sth = $db -> prepare($sql);
$sth -> execute(array(
    ':sq' => $_GET['s'],
));
foreach ($db -> query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['content'];
}?>
```

What I'm trying to do is to make a fulltext search based on an input (:sq), but I keep getting this error:

```
 General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: create index on column, isn't it obvious?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: ALTER TABLE post ADD FULLTEXT index_name(mycolumn);

Comment: And where should I put it?

Comment: it's SQL so you execute it in your database adapting it to the names of your columns